# React under Symfony and Webpack Encore, it doesn't find dependencies

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack

Good day! I have the React application, which I want to make a part of my Symfony project. It is a structure of **src** folder of Symfony project:

```
src
  Bundles
    MyReactApp
      components
        Add.jsx
        Article.jsx
        News.jsx
      data
        newsData.json
    App.css
    App.jsx
    index.jsx
```

It's a start of App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import 'App.css';
import {News} from 'components/News';
import {Add} from 'components/Add';
import newsData from 'data/newsData'


class App extends React.Component {
...
```

I try to execute the command **yarn encore dev** and get an error:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* App.css in ./src/Bundles/MyReactApp/App.jsx
* components/Add in ./src/Bundles/MyReactApp/App.jsx
* components/News in ./src/Bundles/MyReactApp/App.jsx
* data/newsData in ./src/Bundles/MyReactApp/App.jsx
```

It's my webpack.config.js:

```
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .addEntry('react_app', './src/Bundles/MyReactApp/index.jsx')

    .enableReactPreset()

    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    .enableBuildNotifications()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Why I get the error? App.css is located near with App.jsx, but Webpack don't find it. I tried to use *.js instead of *.jsx, but it didn't give any changes.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I have to replace **import 'App.css'** to **import './App.css'** and etc